# How can select object key and value in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> I made with jquery script like this and it gives me back all keys from first object,but i want to select specific one and append it.

```js
$.getJSON("json.json", function(data) {
  var items = [];
  $.each(data.ListData_BS[0], function(key, val) {

    items.push("<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>");
    console.log(data.ListData_BS[0])

  });

  $("<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join("")
  }).appendTo("body");
});
```

and this is my json file.how to be specific to select for example "Cod" or in "MatchDetails", "GameAlias"?

```js
{
  "ListData_BS": [{
    "Cod": "156",
    "CodEx": "18927206",
    "EventDate": "02\/02\/20 12:30",
    "EventDate_US": "02\/02\/20 12:30",
    "EventID": "1780",
    "EventName": "Juventus - Fiorentina",
    "EventTimeToStart": "2 g 2 h 29 m",
    "EventTimeToStart_S": "181775",
    "GameDetails": [{
        "GameAlias": "Finale 1X2",
        "GameClassID": "3",
        "GameCode": null,
        "GameHValue": null,
        "GameName": "1",
        "GameOUValue": null,
        "GameOdd": "1.38",
        "GameOrdiID": "1",
        "GamePerc": "99",
        "GamePkID": 168003962,
        "GameRule": "1-20",
        "Shortcut": null,
        "shcut": null
      },
      {
        "GameAlias": "Finale 1X2",
        "GameClassID": "3",
        "GameCode": null,
        "GameHValue": null,
        "GameName": "X",
        "GameOUValue": null,
        "GameOdd": "5.00",
        "GameOrdiID": "2",
        "GamePerc": "1",
        "GamePkID": 168003964,
        "GameRule": "1-20",
        "Shortcut": null,
        "shcut": null
      }
    ]
  }],
  "ListData_BS": [{
    "Cod": "156",
    "CodEx": "18927206",
    "EventDate": "02\/02\/20 12:30",
    "EventDate_US": "02\/02\/20 12:30",
    "EventID": "1780",
    "EventName": "Juventus - Fiorentina",
    "EventTimeToStart": "2 g 2 h 29 m",
    "EventTimeToStart_S": "181775",
    "GameDetails": [{
        "GameAlias": "Finale 1X2",
        "GameClassID": "3",
        "GameCode": null,
        "GameHValue": null,
        "GameName": "1",
        "GameOUValue": null,
        "GameOdd": "1.38",
        "GameOrdiID": "1",
        "GamePerc": "99",
        "GamePkID": 168003962,
        "GameRule": "1-20",
        "Shortcut": null,
        "shcut": null
      },
      {
        "GameAlias": "Finale 1X2",
        "GameClassID": "3",
        "GameCode": null,
        "GameHValue": null,
        "GameName": "X",
        "GameOUValue": null,
        "GameOdd": "5.00",
        "GameOrdiID": "2",
        "GamePerc": "1",
        "GamePkID": 168003964,
        "GameRule": "1-20",
        "Shortcut": null,
        "shcut": null
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

This Script gives me back al from objects from "ListData_BS",i want to select one or two.

Comment: Select what? What's the expected result?

Comment: I imagine you've pasted twice the objects within that JSON string.

Comment: i want to select for example from first "ListData_BS","Cod" and from first "GameDetails","GameAlias" and to show value